# pandas ordering columns misses values

Tags: python, pandas

Not sure on the right title for this. But I have a need to take out a column from a dataframe, and show the top five results. The column is a mix of integers and n/a results. As an example I create a basic dataframe:

```
regiona col1
a   n/a
a   1
a   200
b   208
b   400
b   560
b   600
c   800
c   1120
c   1200
c   1680
d   n/a
d   n/a
```

And so run:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv')
```

I then created a basic function so I could use this on different columns, so constructed:

```
def max_search(indicator):
    displaced_count = df[df[indicator] != 'n/a']
    table = displaced_count.sort_values([indicator], ascending=[False])
    return table.head(5)
```

But when I run

```
max_search('col1')
```

It returns:

```
    regiona col1
7         c  800
6         b  600
5         b  560
4         b  400
3         b  208
```

So it misses anything greater than 800. The steps I think the function should be doing is:

1. Filter out n/a valyes
2. Return the top five values.

However, it is not returning anything over 800? Am I missing something very obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your dataframe's `dtypes`, now it is `object`. So first make sure  `col1`'s datatype is numeric.
Use `na_values` at [`pd.read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and your function will work as expected:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv', na_values='n/a')
# df.dtypes
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also do:

```
df['col1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col1'], errors='coerce')
df.dropna().sort_values(['col1'], ascending=False).head(5)

   regiona    col1
10       c  1680.0
9        c  1200.0
8        c  1120.0
7        c   800.0
6        b   600.0
```